# JDBC How to update a database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm studying for the OCPJP certification, and actually I'm in the JDBC chapter. I understood that I can update a database in two ways: 1st one is using the JDBC APIs, in particular the updatexxx methods in the ResultSet class; 2nd one is sending a Statement via the execute method so that the DBMS will execute the update itself. So, suppose I have a table named "contacts" and I want to update the "phoneNo" field to "1234567890" where the "name" field is equal to "George". Note that I'm using MySQL. What are the differences, if any, between this

```
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name=\"George\"");
resultset.updateString("phoneNo", "1234567890");
updateRow();
```

and this?

```
statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE contacts SET phoneNo=\"1234567890\" WHERE name=\"George\"");
```

When should I use the 1st method and when the 2nd one? Why should I prefer one of them on the other?
Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options would successfully update your database. But your second option `ExecuteUpdate` is better, for the following reasons:

1) In option 2, most of the work is done by the database server, which is preferable because this is the job of the Database

2) The first option requires the data to be fetched from the DB server, manipulated in your Java program, and then sent back to the database. You are sending multiple requests to the DB server. In the second option, there is only 1 step.

3) In the first option you are using `SELECT * ....` , which is not good practice, because you are retrieving unnecessary data. You should only retrieve the columns that you need, not all the columns. i.e `SELECT PhoneNo`

If you are writing code for optimal performance, you should use option 2, because you are doing a single request, and only passing the relevant data to your DB server

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will use the executeUpdate when you have a lot of updates and lets doing the DB server the work. Like:

```
statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE products SET price=price*10 WHERE category=100");
```

with updateRow you must process every row in your program.

In turn with updateRow could be simpler to set certain columns and you are not forced to make quirky string manipulation to get the sql update statement right.

---

Wrong answer:

If you look into the JDBC API you will see a lot of interfaces. If `executeQuery` works with an `update` or not depends on the implementation. The API says for executeUpdate:

`Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.`

"may be" not "must be". So it depends on the quality of the database driver implementation. If I remember well, MySQL driver will throw an Exception when using update in executeQuery. So you should use the appropieted one in any case.

Comment: So the use of one or of the other depends on the DBMS Driver, right? Anyway executeQuery returns a ResultSet (SELECT x FROM y),  if you try to execute an update you will not have a ResultSet so an Exception is thrown

Comment: No, wait D: there have been a misunderstanding, I'm not trying to execute an update using the executeQuery method, I'm trying to find out what are the differences between executing an update using the executeUpdate method and updating the ResultSet obtained from an executeQuery method

Comment: Raffolox question was on "when to use an updatable ResultSet", not executeQuery() vs. executeUpdate() ?

Answer (score 0):

int executeUpdate(String SQL) : - It returns the no of rows updated in db during the execution of the SQL statement. We can use this method to execute SQL queries like, an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE Statement.

ResultSet executeQuery(String SQL) :- It returns a ResultSet object. We can use this method when we want to execute SELECT queries in db.

Comment: Raffolox question was on "when to use an updatable ResultSet", not executeQuery() vs. executeUpdate() ?

Comment: Requirements for updatable result sets: 
Only specific SELECT statements- simple accesses of a single table-allow you to update or delete rows as you step through them.